# MySQL for set send or share

Tags: mysql

My table is

```
id | first | to | tipe   | message
1  | a     | b  | send   | hallo
2  | b     | a  | share  | hallo
3  | b     | a  | send   | hei
4  | a     | b  | share  | hei
5  | b     | a  | share  | wow
6  | b     | a  | share  | hei
```

how to get / show data like

```
1 |  a | b | send  | hallo
3 |  b | a | send  | hei
4 |  a | b | share | hei
```

*not show if "b" to "a" tipe="share"*

Please help me for this Query, thanks for help :)

Comment: Can you show us what you already have tried?

Comment: So you want to remvoe the 2 row ?

Comment: yes, remove to row 2 ,

Comment: You appear to have no PRIMARY KEY. In time, this may prove problematic.

Comment: For instance, in what sense is the 2nd row 'second'?

Comment: check my post, im now edited, and add the primary key is id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normal select?

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
<WHERE> tipe = 'send' AND/OR message = 'hallo'.....
```

ok. for remove the 2nd row

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE id not in (SELECT ID FROM myTable WHERE first = 'b' AND [to] = 'a' AND tipe = 'share')
```

I might be wrong but this sounds like homework.. :)

Comment: i think he's trying to get something more complicated :D

Comment: no no, :) please check my posting, im edit and add information

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove second row, Try this query:-

```
SELECT ID, FIRST, TO, TIPE, MESSAGE
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE FIRST = 'B'
AND TO = 'A'
TIPE = 'Share';
```